# Nueva aplicación .Net, proyecto Web Application

Tags: .net, aplicación-web, web

Me encuentro ante el desafío de un proyecto de desarrollo de una aplicación web.

Un sitio web que contenga un formulario "ABM (Alta, baja, modificación)" con los siguientes controles:

`TextBox`, `DropDownList`, `Button`, `Label` y `Gridview`.

El usuario debe poder agregar un nuevo registro y al presionar el botón "agregar" debe guardarse y mostrarse en la grilla. Si el usuario desea modificarlo, al presionar sobre el registro, se le mostrarán los datos en los controles correspondientes permitiendo modificar su valor y al presionar "Actualizar" se guardarán, teniendo la posibilidad de presionar "Cancelar" en caso de que así lo desee y no se actualice el campo y por último eliminar el registro presionando "eliminar", botón que debe aparecer al costado de cada registro en la grilla.

Adicionalmente debo conectar la aplicación a una base de datos o almacenar la información dentro de variables de inicio de sesión.

Por cada acción, debe aparecer un nuevo mensaje que indica que se realizó la acción deseada.

La aplicación debe ser desarrollada utilizando ".Net", proyecto "Web Application".

Comment: bienvenido al sitio, me gustó la manera en que redactaste la pregunta y la PD, te recomiendo que visites el tour del sitio: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y le des una lectura al FAQ de cómo preguntar http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Por otro lado, aprovechando que conoces C#, ASP.net es el framework que se utiliza, donde tienes WebForms, MVC, WebAPI, SignalR, Web Pages. Para desarrollar en la web, debes conocer JavaScript by default, es decir, siempre estudia JavaScript puro (te será más fácil luego usar librerías como jQuery y frameworks como AngularJS, EmberJS, etc) Hace un tiempo hice un workshop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY para que aprendas Razor (motor de renderizado de ASP.net MVC) hice este documento hace unos años: http://www.slideshare.net/fredyfx/tutorial-ms-web-matrixv4 que se mantiene vigente

Comment: no sabria como responder a tu consulta. Si sabes C# cual es tu problema para armar aunque sea una web basica?

Comment: Para una mayor información, te recomiendo ser estudiante a tiempo parcial o tiempo completo en: https://mva.microsoft.com/ https://www.udemy.com/ https://www.coursera.org/ https://www.edx.org/ y si el inglés es una limitante, vamos a derribarla con: https://www.duolingo.com/ https://www.memrise.com/ http://www.engvid.com/ éxitos y bendiciones, a darle con todo el power 2.0! Hoy en día se requiere organizar mejor el tiempo que conseguir dinero para estudiar algo, por cierto, si quieres códigos de ejemplo: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ :D

Comment: Soy el único que no ve la pregunta? Está planteando un proyecto pero ninguna pregunta. De hecho tampoco está copiando código de referencia para ayudarlo. Creo que debería votarse como demasiado ámplia. PD: Parece una pregunta de "haz mi tarea."

Comment: Perdón Agustín, mi post original era otro pero fue editado. En mi post original comentaba que no tenía los conocimientos para realizar el proyecto y consultaba si alguien podía indicarme por dónde comenzar, en qué me tenía que instruir para poder realizar la tarea.